# sum(sum(A.*B)) (matlab notation) in modern fortran

Tags: fortran

May you suggest me an efficient way to implement

```
sum(sum(C))
```

where

```
C=A.*B
```

Here I'm using matlab notation, that means that fo A and B square matrices, A.*B is a matrix of the same dimension where its element i-j is the multiplication of the element i-j of A and the element i-j of b, that is

Cij = Aij*Bij

Then, sum(sum(C)) means the sum of all element of the matrix C.

Of course, It is easy to do a DO-loop calculating this, but this operation is inside another loop cycle, so I must to do it several times and that's why I think that could be a more efficient way.

Of course, the "sum(sum())" part is easy, I just can't see an efficient way to do A.*B

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran question. Add a specific version tag for version-specific questions, but this ne is not one of them. Please note that explicit DO loops are ften the fastest way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation you want is just `sum(a*b)` in Fortran. If `a` and `b` are vectors then the result is the dot product. `s = a(1)*b(1)+a(2)*b(2)+..` But if they are matrices then I don't know what to call it.

Here is a quick overview of linear algebra in the two environments

| Operation | Matlab | Fortran |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Element Multiplication | `c = a .* b` | `c = a * b` |
| Matrix Product | `c = a * b` | `c = matmul(a,b)` |
| Element Sum | `sum(sum(c))` | `sum(c)` |
| Transpose | `a.'` | `transpose(a)` |
| Inner Product | `a.'*b` | `dot_product(a,b)` |
| Outer Product | `a*b.'` | `matmul(a,transpose(b))` |
| Maximum Value | `max(max(a))` | `maxval(a)` |
| Minimum Value | `min(min(a))` | `minval(a)` |

By the way, most compilers will recognize the do loops and vectorize them resulting in just as fast code as the above. If fact, in my testing the `do-loop` method is about 3-5% faster than the compact methods. I usually prefer the compact notation and only if I need to optimize only some specific code I would write out the loops. Remember to compile with `AVX2` enabled, and that the compiler unrolls the loops allowing for some more efficient memory access.